# ERROR TypeError: can't access property , this.child is undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I'd like to call the function "initMap", declared in the child "UpdatePinComponent", from my parent component "ApiaryComponent".
Here is my parent ts file :

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { UpdatePinComponent } from '../leaflet-map/update-pin/update-pin.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-apiary',
  templateUrl: './apiary.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./apiary.component.scss']
})


@Input('class')

export class ApiaryComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild(UpdatePinComponent) child!:UpdatePinComponent;
// I can't remove the "!", or else it would print : 
// "Property 'child' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor."

(...)

getApiaryAttributes(apiaryId)
    {
        this.child.initMap();
    }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.getApiaryAttributes(this.apiaryId);
  }

}
```

But when I load the project, I am getting this console error :

ERROR TypeError: can't access property "initMap", this.child is undefined

EDIT : here is a bit of the html code, if it can help :

```html
    <ul class="actionApiary">
      <li>
        <button class="ApiaryItem" id="addApiaryItem" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#addApiaryModal">+</button>
      </li>
      <li>
        <button class="ApiaryItem" (click)="getApiaryAttributes(apiaryId)" id="updateApiaryItem" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modifApiaryModal">m</button>
      </li>
      <li>
        <button class="ApiaryItem" id="deleteApiaryItem" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#deleteApiaryModal">-</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: How does your HTML look like? Where is UpdatePinComponent defined in the parent?

Comment: With ! you are telling to TypeScript, don't check for UpdatePinComponent I have it defined, but it looks like you haven't done that.

Comment: Try to move `myFunction()` into the hook `ngAfterViewInit()`

Comment: But without !, it prints an error. Plus, even by disabling the strict mode, and by the removing the "!", the console error at the ends remains the same.

Comment: Disabling strict mode should't be solution for error messages, ever. When you remove ! TypeScript will tell you that you haven't defined UpdatePinComponent. And TypeScript is right you haven't defined UpdatePinComponent. You cannot call function of something that is NOT defined.

Comment: @onetwo12 I don't get it, since it's an existing child that has been called, how does it is not definied ?

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70801522/viewchild-initializer-error-on-angular-13

Comment: @ViewChild(UpdatePinComponent) child!:UpdatePinComponent; is looking for child that is defined in the class or the HTML code, but I guess you need just to call the class without initializing it in your parent.

Comment: @onetwo12 I tried UpdatePinComponent.initMap(), but the code would say :
Property 'initMap' does not exist on type 'typeof UpdatePinComponent'

Comment: Please edit your question and post the whole code from UpdatePinComponent and ApiaryComponent and the corresponding HTML.

Comment: `child?: UpdatePinComponent` would be more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

A child component is not assured to be available is the ngOnInit lifecycle hook. Instead you should implement the ngAfterViewInit hook and call myFunction there.

Here is the official documentation about it: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#responding-to-view-changes

Comment: I called myFunction in ngAfterViewInit , but I get the same problem.

Comment: what is the html of the ApiaryComponent ? You can edit your question

Comment: I am not sure if I can share it, but the method initMap() is not called in the html code itself and beside that, the code is working properly.

Comment: it is to check how the UpdatePinComponent is retrieved from the html by the ViewChild decorator

Comment: Can we use children methods without having the children comp in the html ?

Comment: In your case with @ViewChild no.

Comment: If there another way to call a child method, then? I can't show the whole html code, but once again, it doesn't interfer at all in the function.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, using a constructor seems to be the proper way. It failed at the first time because I didn't initialized UpdatePinComponent as a provider in the app.module.ts.
It still doesn't work, but it must come from leaflet, so this is a different problem.